# Switching from mongoid to postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have found that in order to aggregate on a related table in mongoid(rails mongo driver) you have to embed objects as the `$lookup` mongodb function will not be made available.

This causes all sorts of development slowdowns in Rails. Therefore, I am switching to Postgres to develop an app with a lot of interdependable tables.

According to speed tests [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/marc-linster/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-new-developer-reality)  and [here](http://www.aptuz.com/blog/is-postgres-nosql-database-better-than-mongodb/) it seems that Postgres can perfrom as well as or better than mongo on aggregations and queries.

We have multiple tables of ~20 million rows. Is it correct to switch to an older Postgres technology in this situation?

Comment: If this seems like an improper question for SO, I can delete it and move it to another site if suggested

Comment: What do you mean by 'older technology'? Postgres is very actively being developed

Comment: Yes, but most new frameworks are going in the way of mongo because it is schemaless and can be easier adjusted for big data. And frankly just because nosql is a 2017 trend.

Comment: Well, what are those 'most' frameworks? Nosql was a trend a few years back yes, but I'm not seeing that so much these days.

Comment: That's an interesting point, it may be normalizing now where nosql and rdbms are both considered on trend. meteor framework uses mongo, so does the mean stack

Comment: Don't think so, google trends is dead flat for last 6 years. https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2011-01-24%202017-02-24&q=nosql,postgresql

Comment: Wow, mongo and postgres are about tied https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2011-01-24%202017-02-24&q=mongodb,postgresql